# Authorization for google pay without CVV

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing, google-pay

I am trying to integrate google pay into one of our websites. The backend already has gateway implementation to process the raw card info. Here I would like to use direct integration of google pay where I can decrypt the payment token and extract the credit card info and pass it to the gateway. But here I don't see the cvv info after decryption. After researching I found out that the google pay does not provide cvv. Here I just want to know how can I implement google pay integration without cvv. How are the other websites are integrating the google pay using direct integration without cvv?

Comment: Unless you're PCI certified it's ok that you do NOT have the security code (or any other details for the matter) anywhere. Just ask the user to provide it and use it alongside the other details.

Comment: It's not clear, but it sounds like you're trying to do something that doesn't make sense. If you're integrating Google Pay, they're billing the card. Your existing gateway won't be involved at all.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I am using google pay to fetch the card details stored in the users google account. From the docs it is mentioned that Google provides the encrypted payment token which consists of card details. We can decrypt the token to get the card info and process it using any gateway. So here also I am trying to do the same thing.  Please explain your suggestions here.

Comment: The CVV wouldn't be stored in the user's account because PCI forbids storing the CVV in any manner.

Comment: Are you using Stripe to process these payments?  If so you would not decrypt the token.  Most Stripe payment flows that involve Google Pay bypass the server entirely.  https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button, https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#apple-pay-and-google-pay

Comment: @RyanM. We are not using stripe. We are directly integrating google pay into our website. If google pay does not provide cvv, should we explicitly show the input field to the user to enter CVV? Is that the recommended solution?

Comment: @googlePayTestbhn  yes, if you are sending that information to some other gateway, you have to ask user for their CVV. But you should never ever store CVV nor even the other card data unless you can ensure PCI compliancy of your own website. Also curious, why would you want to extract GooglePay info and pass it to some other gateway? Doesn't the gateway itself provide a user interface for completing the payment?